# When Services are stopped after app goes into background on Android 8.0

Tags: android

The service will stop when the application goes into background in Android 8.0 device. My question is whether there is a default time after which services are stopped?

Comment: I don't think that there is some exact timeout for all devices. You just have to expect it to stop in some time. If you want it to continue working - implement foreground service

Comment: if you need a socket connection it's better to implement a foregroundservice that runs for as long as your activity is running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an app goes into the background, it has a window of few minutes (based on my observations its around 1 - 2 minutes, even less on some other deivces) in which it is still allowed to create and use services. The system stops the app's background services, just as if the app had called the services' Service.stopSelf() methods.

Google has just revealed the DP1 of the next iteration of android: Android O. There are many new exciting features and under the hood performance improvements in the newest version of android.

For android developers there are four groundbreaking changes:

1.Background execution limits

2.Location updates limit

3.Removing of implicit broadcasts

4.Notification channels

Whenever your applications run in the background using services, your application consumes two precious resources: 1) Memory and 2) Battery.

These two are limited resources on the mobile devices and most of the low to mid-range devices doesn’t have plenty of memory or battery inside it.

Suppose, if your application is doing some very intensive tasks in the background and using the larger amount of RAM to perform that task, then this will create the very junky user experience, especially if the user is using another resource-intensive app, such as playing a game or watching a video in foreground.

Check the [new updated docs by google.](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)

also [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground)

for reference [here](https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/how-to-handle-background-services-in-android-o-f96783e65268)

Answer (score 0):

in Oreo after flushing app, service stop 5-10 seconds. when you minimise app not flush that time app goes to background.