# Android background service stopped/paused on Huawei

Tags: java, android, service, background, huawei-mobile-services

I have developed an Android app that has a background service that runs endlessly and saves on a local SqLite DB the results of bluetooth scan and GPS positions. Only on Huawei devices this service seems to be paused or stopped for some minutes (I noticed that after inserting some log into the code): in theese minutes any log is written.
. I tried without success to  change some settings of device (battery optimization).
Do you have some advice to solve the problem?

Below you can find a snipped of the service.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

public MyService() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    ...
    ...
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        startForeground(1031, getNotification());
    }
    final Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
    ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            MyServiceBinder binder = (MyServiceBinder) service;
            started = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            started = false;
        }
    };
    bindService(serviceIntent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private Notification getNotification() {
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("channel_01", "My Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "channel_01");
    builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_onesignal_default);
    return builder.build();
}


public class MyServiceBinder extends Binder {
    MyService getService() {
        return MyService.this;
    }
}

private void stopForegroundService()
{
    // Stop foreground service and remove the notification.
    stopForeground(true);

    // Stop the foreground service.
    stopSelf();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        stopForegroundService();
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        //Restart after 5 secs
        Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GenericUtility.launchService(MyService.class, getApplication());
            }
        }, 5000);

    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    ...
    ...
    initScanLoop();
    initLocationManager();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return new MyServiceBinder();
}

 @Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    boolean res = super.onUnbind(intent);
    return res;
}

/*Init bluetooth handler*/
private void initScanLoop() {
    final Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    h.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scanLeDevice();
            hBeacon.postDelayed(this, SCAN_DURATION + 10000);
        }
    });
}

private void scanLeDevice() {
    if(mLEScanner != null && !scanning.get() && !stopScan) {
        scanning.set(true);
        mLEScanner.startScan(null, settings, mScanCallback);
        Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(scanning.get()) {
                    stopScanLeDevice();
                }
            }
        }, SCAN_DURATION);

    }
}

private void stopScanLeDevice() {
    scanning.set(false);
    if(mLEScanner != null) {
        mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
    }
}
/*Finish bluetooth handler*/

/*Init GPS handler*/
private void initLocationManager() {
     locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
     createLocationChangedCallback();
     locationListener = new BeaconScanLocationListener(locationChangedCallback);
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}

private void createLocationChangedCallback() {
    locationChangedCallback = new LocationChangedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void callback(final Location location) {
            try {
                //GPS callcback
            } catch(Exception e) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void enabledDisabled(boolean enabled) {
        }
    };
}
/*Finish GPS handler*/
}
```

**UPDATE**

I improved app functionality replacing bluetooth scanning with monitoring beacon in region function of Android Beacon Library.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54547511/9060917

Comment: are you using app like  battery saver?

Comment: Have a look at this it may help https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Comment: Can you use an alternative mechanism for getting this information to a `Service`, such as a `JobScheduler`?

Comment: @IvanWooll thaks for your suggest but I've tried without success

Comment: @PPartisan in which way?

Comment: You say you need to periodically scan for bluetooth devices and GPS locations. Couldn't you do that with a `JobScheduler` task, rather than in a Service?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure in settings for app can run in background for Huawei

you can check out this link [here](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/content/en-us00428704/)

Answer (score -1):

This problem can you fix it by put your device in App launch normally the app manage by Huawei but you must make it manage manually after that Huawei can't put the service in sleep mode.